# Master - Detail Gridview column hiding Devexpress

Tags: devexpress, master-detail, aspxgridview

I have a multiple Parent-Child Gridview. The problem is Parent gridview Column name is Cost ($) and the ($) symbol is hiding when i expand the Child gridview  and get it back when i minimize the Child gridview (Devexpress). The Parent-Child gridview is present in the AspxCallbackPanel and in the PopupControl.

```
<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="cbpCartDetails" runat="server" 
        OnCallback="cbpCartDetails_Callback" ClientInstanceName="cbpCartDetails">
    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="cbpCartDetails_EndCallBack" />
    <PanelCollection>
    <dx:PanelContent ID="pnlCartDetails">
        <dx:ASPxPopupControl ClientInstanceName="popCartDetails" Width="600px" 
            Height="250px" CloseAction="CloseButton" MaxWidth="800px" MaxHeight="800px" 
            MinHeight="150px" MinWidth="150px" ID="popCartDetails"
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
            runat="server" EnableViewState="false" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" 
            PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" EnableHierarchyRecreation="false" 
            Modal="true">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl2" 
                                               runat="server">

                    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdBuildingCartEst" Width="100%" 
                                     Theme="SoftOrange" KeyFieldName="CarttypeId"
                                     ClientInstanceName="grdBuildingCartEst">
                        <Columns>
                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CartType" />
                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="NumberOfCart" />
                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Cost" />
                        </Columns>

                        <Templates>
                            <DetailRow>
                                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdFloorsCartEst" 
                                        Width="100%" 
                                        Theme="SoftOrange" 
                                        KeyFieldName="CarttypeId" 
                                        OnInit="grdFloorsCartEst_Init" 
                                        OnBeforePerformDataSelect=
                                           "grdFloorsCartEst_BeforePerformDataSelect" 
                                        ClientInstanceName="grdFloorsCartEst">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
                                            FieldName="CartSize" />
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
                                            FieldName="NumberOfCart" />
                                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn 
                                            FieldName="Cost" />
                                    </Columns>    
                                </dx:ASPxGridView>
                            </DetailRow>
                        </Templates>

                        <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="true" />

                    </dx:ASPxGridView>                   
                </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
    </dx:PanelContent>
</PanelCollection>
```

Screen shot 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb1QX.png

Screen shot 2 (Error)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AghdG.png

Answer (score 0):

notice, in the code you've posted, there is no "Cost ($)" string for the master grid column, only FieldName="Cost". Most probably "Cost ($)" is set to column header at codebehind during Page_Load or some other event.

When you expand the child grid there happens a callback and the event code at codebehind where you set Cost ($) is not executed. So, you need to make sure the column header of the master grid is set to "Cost ($)" during child grid expand callback. To be 100% sure, post/attach the codebehind part of your page/control to the question's text.

Comment: Actually the symbol ($) is coming from xml file.

Comment: @mohamedsami so you need to make sure you update the master grid column header upon child grid expand callback. You may or may not need that initial xml file. It can be done in the callback event handler like: grdBuildingCartEst.Columns("Cost").Caption = "Cost ($)";